# How to run code after the last post has completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
    $.post('/Secure/File/PhysicalFileHandler.ashx?custId=whatever&idx=' + i, function (data) {
        ids += data + '|';
        if (i == numFiles-1) {
            ids = ids.substring(0, ids.length - 1);
        }
    });

}
```

How could I execute a chunk of code after the last post has finished?  The method I was trying above does not work (`i` is `==` to `numFiles` already when it gets there).  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat common problem - the "i" you are referencing is handled by the for function, and commonly the for function has finished executing by the time the callback is triggered (in which case, the "i" is equal to numFiles already). There are a couple solutions to this: one would be to change the callback to this:

```
(function (i) {
  return function (data) {
    ids += data + '|';
    if (i == numFiles-1) {
        ids = ids.substring(0, ids.length - 1);
    }
})(i)
```

What this does is create a new function for each execution of the loop, and each time the function has it's own reference to "i" - instead of looking back to the for loop's definition/value of i, it has it's own local parameter to refer to. This has to be done by returning another function since you need the code to execute during the first pass of the for loop, ensuring the right value is preserved when the callback is triggered.

One other alternative is to wrap the entire post statement in a function with it's own copy of i - I don't think there's too much difference between the two. Personally, I favor the approach in the above snippet more since it minimizes the effect of the overall flow of the code, but opinions will vary on this.

Answer (score 0):

The posts may not finish in the order they were started. You must count each one as it finishes to know that all have finished.

```
var finishedCount = 0; // track number of calls finished
for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $.post('/Secure/File/PhysicalFileHandler.ashx?custId=whatever&idx=' + i, function (data) {
            ids += data + '|';
            finishedCount = finishedCount + 1; // increment number of calls finished
            if (finishedCount == numFiles) { // run only when all calls have finished
                ids = ids.substring(0, ids.length - 1);
            }
        });
    })(i); // capture value of i in closure
}
```

Edit: Capturing value of i in the closure is no longer necessary since i is not used in the post callback function in this version.